# Wait for result from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, concurrency, synchronization

In an activity (say A) I have to perform a certain task depending on the result of another activity (B). I start activity B using startActivityForResult(). The pseudo code is something like this:
(in activity A)

```
//Statements
//startActivityForResult(activityB)
//get the result in some local variable for activity A. result is a boolean
//if(result==true) do something
//else do something else
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that after starting the activity B, it doesn't wait for the result to arrive from B. Instead, it proceeds and uses the default value of the boolean result.
Any solution?

If this particular block was in another thread, i could write a synchronized block and 
issue a wait() after starting the activity B, and then notify() in the onActivityResult(). 
But since there's just a single thread, that's not an option right?

Should mention that activityB takes a user input of Yes/No and returns that. So on starting it, the result is not immediately available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any solution?

Put your last two lines from your code listing in `onActivityResult()`, as is [described in the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

More importantly, you also need to rewrite activityB to actually follow the instructions for using `setResult()` to pass results back to activityA.

Comment: I have no trouble in getting the result from activityB. I get the desired result back. But in activityA, after the startActivityForResult() line, it just proceeds using the default value of the variable result.
Should mention that activityB takes a user input of Yes/No and returns that. So on starting it, the result is not immediately available.

Comment: @Alabhya: "But in activityA, after the startActivityForResult() line, it just proceeds using the default value of the variable result." -- of course. `startActivityForResult()` is not a blocking call, and the activity is not yet started when it returns.

Comment: Oh. I thought it would be blocking. So what could the alternative  way be? Is there a way to use wait-notify or something like that.

Comment: @Alabhya: "So what could the alternative way be?" -- re-read my answer.

Comment: How did i not realize this before asking.
And how did i not realize this after reading your answer!
Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare If it isn't blocking, how can you wait for the result? I am having the exact same issue as the OP.

Comment: @Johnny: "If it isn't blocking, how can you wait for the result?" -- you don't wait. You process the result when it arrives in `onActivityResult()`. This is a very common pattern in event-driven programming, and event-driven programming has been a very common approach for the past quarter-century or so.

Comment: Thanks for responding.. I just needed to move ALL of the code that needed to be executed after the result. I had a eureka moment. :)